# Using gRPC communicate Spring Boot application together with consul or Eureka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, grpc, grpc-java

How can we use grcp communication with spring boot application. And how we can use common service discovery method for use with grpc to get end point of spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

For service discovery, implement your own [NameResolver](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/NameResolver.html).

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to get instance discovery client. It help to call all servers using revers poxing.

```
@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
```

and below method help to call all the services using service name

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/senduser")
public ResponseEntity<?> sendMessageToAllServices() {
    user u=null;
    List<ServiceInstance> server=discoveryClient.getInstances("grpc-server");
    for (ServiceInstance serviceInstance : server) {

        String hostName=serviceInstance.getHost();
        int gRpcPort=Integer.parseInt(serviceInstance.getMetadata().get("grpc.port"));

        ManagedChannel channel=ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(hostName,gRpcPort).usePlaintext(true).build();
        UserServiceBlockingStub stub=UserServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

        UserDetail user=UserDetail.newBuilder()
                    .setName("Thamira")
                    .setEmail("Thamira1005@gmail.com")
                    .setAge(24).setGender(Gender.Male)
                    .setPassword("password").build();

        u=stub.createUser(user);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok("User "+u);
}
```

we can change register as a consul or eureka. This method support both of that.